# Change the server/instance without changing the connection string to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, hosts

I need to create a test environment.

I will want to connect multiple programs to a different instance of DB but I do not want to change their connection strings.

I can change what I want on my machine but I can not change anything on the test server (unless it's really necessary)

I have installed a SQL server installed on a machine called srvtest and wanted it in my environment to be known by [production/work]

Any ideas?

Comment: Different instance of db? Do you mean you need to connect to a different SQL Server instance or a different db on the same instance?

Comment: I don't see why you're so against changing the connection strings, that absolutely how you should do this. However, you *could* leave them unchanged and instead create a SQL Server alias using the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Connection strings are used by *applications*. You don't need to change anything on SQL Server itself or the `hosts` file. The applications can use different configuration files for different environments. For example, .NET applications have different `app.config` files for Debug and Release. ASP.NET applications have different `web.config` files per *environment* as well.

Comment: @dfundako  They are different servers.
On the test server there is no instance of WORK
I can do everything just in the hosts file change the production IP to the test IP the problem is that on the test server there is no such instance WORK

Comment: @Paulos02 the instance is part of the *server name*. Essentially, you are asking for a way to connect to a different server. Again, this is the responsibility of the *application*. What application is this? Stack? Language?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I know this, but the problem is that there are many places where I have change. I have .Net, PHP, Magento, WordPress, WebServices etc ...
and I'm not too keen to alter these config files all.
It would be simpler to "trick" my local server so that it connects to the machine I want

Comment: I think then the quick fix is to create the same WORK instance on the test server.
And swap the production / test names in the HOSTS file so everything will work fine.
Thanks for the replies

Comment: @Paulos02 you don't need to do that. In this case you can use a [SQL Server Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-2017) to make a server appear by a different name. Fiddling with HOSTS is *never* a quick fix

Comment: @Paulos02 btw since this is a 100% DBA question you should ask at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok @PanagiotisKanavos I'll see your solution with SQL Server Alias

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169988/discussion-between-paulos02-and-panagiotis-kanavos).